# Wireshark ------- Source port: timbuktu-srv2?

Tags: networking, sockets, p2p, wireshark

all I am trying to establish peer to peer (UDP) communication via firefox extension. I have python program that works on command line. I built a xpcom component using it. But surprisingly I could only receive message through it from command line python program.

We tried following ( All working on localhost  ) :

**Firefox XPCOM component as sender** --> **firefox XPCOM component as receiver**   -- did not work

**Python command line as sender** -->  **firefox xpcom component as receiver**      -- Worked

**firefox xpcom component as sender**   -->  **Python command line as receiver**    -- did not work

**Python commandline as sender** --> **python command line as receiver**            -- Worked

When we Observed packets using wireshark we got some differences --

**Firefox xpcom to python command line** AND **firefox xpcom to firefox xpcom** (which did not worked) have packet record as follows

Such type of packets(source port marked as non number) produced by

Winsock(C++)

XPCOM component

C#

```
...UDP  Source port: timbuktu-srv2  Destination port: 30000
```

**python command line to python command line** AND **Python command line to XPCOM** (which did worked) have packet record as follows

```
... UDP Source port: 30000  Destination port: 30000
```

I do not know much about the networking, but the record marked `..Source port: timbuktu-srv2..` fails to reach its destination .

I have been trying p2p communication using Python, C++ (Winsock) , C# but could only succeeded with Python only difference I could observe is such type of specific record with python ..

Can some networking gurus flash light over it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timbuktu-srv2` you're seeing is just the result of Wireshark looking up the actual port number against its list of known services.  If you check the [IANA assigned port numbers list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers), you'll see this entry:

```
timbuktu-srv2   1418/udp   Timbuktu Service 2 Port
```

...so that just means your application used 1418 as the source port of the UDP packet it sent.  30000 doesn't get turned into a text service name because your local services database doesn't have an entry for that port number.

This, on its own, doesn't explain the issue - really, the server side should accept the client using whatever source port it wants.  However, it seems likely in this case that the reciever side is only accepting packets with a source port of 30000.  To achieve that, you need to bind the socket to the local address `INADDR_ANY` and port 30000 before sending your packet(s).